# Spring-Boot client authentication configuration.

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, keystore, restful-authentication

First off, I'm new to Spring-Boot and SSL in general, but I've spent several days researching and am basically trying to get a simple Spring-Boot application configured with Client Authentication.

I've set up a connector like so:

```
private Connector createSslConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    try {
        File keystore = getKeyStoreFile();
        File truststore = keystore;
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setPort(sslPort);
        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
        protocol.setKeystorePass("changeit");
        protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststore.getAbsolutePath());
        protocol.setTruststorePass("changeit");
        protocol.setKeyAlias("apitester");
        protocol.setClientAuth("need");
        return connector;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("cant access keystore: [" + "keystore"
                + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
    }
}
```

And a controller that looks like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/test/{identifier}")
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> test(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String identifier) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("hello: " + identifier, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

However, once I launch my application I can use a browser to navigate to localhost:sslport/hello/test/xxxx and get a response without any type of client certificate loaded. I was expecting to be prompted for a client certificate.

Comment: have you tried  with `https://localhost:sslport/hello/test/xxxx`?

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot uses tomcat (embedded) web container by default.

As it is called out [tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_BIO,_NIO_and_NIO2), we have to set it to **true** to enforce the propagation of *valid certificate chain* from the client before accepting a connection. Setting **want** will allow the client to provide a certificate but not absolutely required.

I doubt if "need" makes any meaning for the container.

```
 protocol.setClientAuth("need");
```